# Export Column Headers to csv using FMDB and CHCSVWriter

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, csv, fmdb

I've created an app that I'm storing data in a SQLite db using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

I'm exporting some Tables from the db to a csv using [CHCSVWriter](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser).

What's the best method for exporting the column header row?
Should I loop once using the 'orderedKeys' and write 'columnName' first then move to writing the content?

*Code*

```
FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[Utility getDatabasePath]];
[db open];
FMResultSet *results = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM tblScores"];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
NSString *document = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/demo.csv", documentsDirectory];

CHCSVWriter *csvWriter = [[CHCSVWriter alloc] initForWritingToCSVFile:document];

while([results next]) {
    NSDictionary *resultRow = [results resultDictionary];
    NSArray *orderedKeys = [[resultRow allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    //iterate over the dictionary
    for (NSString *columnName in orderedKeys) {
        id value = [resultRow objectForKey:columnName];
        [csvWriter writeField:value];
    }
    [csvWriter finishLine];
}
[csvWriter closeStream];
```

Comment: I've found the following issue: https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/issues/84